# How to put 'And' clause to many-to-many

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

can you help me out again ?

Got 2 tables! here:

```
Products
ID             |          Name
1                         X Product
2                         Y Product
3                         Z Product

Filters
ID             |          Name
1                         X Filter
2                         Y Filter
3                         Z Filter

Product_Filter
Product_ID     |          Filter_ID
1                         1
1                         2
2                         1
2                         2
2                         3
3                         3
```

This pivot table contains:

X Product has X Filter and Y Filter

Y Product has X Filter and and Y Filter and Z Filter

Z Product has Z Filter

I have this sql code which I can get X and Y Product by defining X Filter's ID.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `products`.* 
FROM `products` 
  JOIN `filters` ON `products`.`id` = `filters`.`id` 
WHERE `product_filter`.`filter_id` = 1;
```

What if I want to get products only contains X Filter and Z Filter ?
like putting and clause like this but it doesn't work of course.:

```
WHERE `product_filter`.`filter_id` = 1 
  and 'product_filter'.'filter_id' = 69;
```

Comment: Change `and 'product_filter'.'filter_id' = 69;` to use backticks and not single quotes around the field names like the previous line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use group by and having count while matching 2 criteria at the same time on a single column something as

```
select
p.* from Products p
join Product_Filter pf on pf.Product_ID = p.ID
join Filters f on f.ID = pf.Filter_ID
where pf.filter_id in (1,69)
group by p.ID
having count(*) = 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22c96/1

Comment: Awesome but, what if I put many 'and's? having count must be dynamic ye ?

Comment: no using `and` meaning you are asking mysql to find a row with 2 or more value for `filter_id` for the same row which is always false or in other words you can not have a row having 2 different column values. Hence you need to use `in` with `group by` and `having count` So if you have multiple values to match right now its 2 values so having count is 2 for 3 it needs to be 3 and so on.

Comment: now I get it I guess. so I can do this right ? where pf.filter_id in (1,69,254,34)
group by p.ID
having count(*) = 2

Comment: and this will give me a product or products which have 1 69 254 and 34 filters

Comment: No you are passing 4 values so if you need to find product ids having all the 4 associated `filter_id` then it should `having count(*)=4`